# How can I remove the ASK search from awesome bar?

Tags: firefox

In awesome bar of Firefox 4, when I type any url, it open with ask search engine result. How can I remove it?

I didn't install Ask toolbar, or I guess it didn't happen for any add-on. Some program must have changed it. How could reset to default?

Answer (score 2):

Ask toolbar installs with other software, and has its own uninstaller

1. Uninstall it from programs and settings
2. Remove ask toolbar from addons if its still there
3. Click on the down arrow on your search bar - select *manage search engines* and pick your preferred search engine.